# Retrofit send base64 encoded string in parameters

Tags: android, base64, retrofit

Hi all i am trying to send base64 encoded image as string in request paramters from my app. It give me 400 and bad request error can any one please help me to sort this out

Here is the retrofit request

```
@GET("/api/storeProfileImages")
public void storeProfileImages(@QueryMap Map<String, Object> options, Callback<CreateUpdateResp> response);
```

Here is request i see in logs

```
HTTP POST http://testdomain:8080/api/storeProfileImages?profileType=NETWORK_PROFILE&userid=839336562814130&imageData=%2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD%2F2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB%0AAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH%2F2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB%0AAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH%2FwAARCAELAMgDASIA%0AAhEBAxEB%2F8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL%2F8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA%0AAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3%0AODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm%0Ap6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4%2BTl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3%2BPn6%2F8QAHwEA%0AAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL%2F8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx%0ABhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElK%0AU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3%0AuLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3%2BPn6%2F9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD8ifiL%0AZaTo3jnx1pdl4b8G21rF4x8Z6fYWMHgTwf8AY9NstO8Q6vpunWH%2FACB%2F%2BgWeM88dRg54KAWMjmI6%0AD4Xwfun%2FAIQzwf2POMaPkfj1znJC8978U5N3xG%2BIolOP%2BK%2F8ZYGM4%2F4rPV89j1x356d64qx8qKdF%0AA44yc4%2FvYxwfbvjoTzur80nVxMcQ7LTS107W5p%2Bbb6d7uS0eif8AZ%2BDy%2FKVQwX1nA5D0t%2Fxj%2B0bt%0AXd27dNLvVJJWXMT3EdtJHN5ejeHIhDgnPgvwf%2Fef%2FqD%2B4%2FEr0BbdzlxcW8ef%2BJV4c%2F8ACL8HdtwO%0AP%2BKP4zxkdTkcghiezlt45IJvTj%2B96uPXOQPw56k4NefajZ%2BW82JOvThv9vHb6%2Fr3xXJ7XE95fj%2F8%0Akej9Qyn%2FAKEGQ%2FdP%2FIPtdpj%2FAJBfh3Pr%2FwAIX4Q9fT%2BxvT%2FOawJNUiicgWWgccf8ij4O6Zc%2F9AY4%0A%2FmMgYOd1PgzLkdT26DjOPXH59Pc1Vu7Rdx4we%2BCSepA7%2B3qeoznOaf13EfzL7n595f1p1uU8vyGs%0AmvqOQy2v%2FwAY9K6%2BJJ%2B9K9tH3j5Xu5RC%2BaQmQadoJ9f%2BKU8H9ctjj%2Bxzz1I%2BvqDUTassbf8AHloP%0Ab%2FmU%2FB57vz%2FyB%2B4B9fvDgkHETFo4z5aiXj%2B8P7zAY9Dwf155yca4Rvss95Iv%2Biwzj9%2BG%2FwCXzLAW%0AH8uc9Djs2T67iP5l93%2FBK%2FsrIP8AoScP%2FfD%2FAOQOjGvfIcaf4cOT8o%2F4RLwcOmQRn%2Bxu%2B0tzz7Z4%0AOTL4hfEw%2Bx6MQMY%2F4pLwf3L56aOeu0dfwzzmG08N%2BINVtPMh0e%2F8rHA%2BwHIw0meQM%2Bh7cbgBncaW%0APwT4ou5vs39lSxxnpOcjdgsPXHT35JPOc5axzo83%2B39UvhTvyuSuuaS%2Bfdy3fLzO8Hwxh8yxD%2Fs%2F%0AIle1rq91701u1s1bXta8m7SKthqOtazqFrpWm6fpd1d3c%2F2aG3g8JeDjefefBBOj4z1OPp71%2BgHg%0AX4JeGPBukT6v460fRvFmuwWNjqE%2BhT%2BGvB9rpGm2W5%2F%2BJhqX%2FEn7%2FXjI4JOKi%2FZx%2BA0Vhs8SajFn%0AVdRn%2FsfwmL6Aj7P%2FAGiT%2FaWv9OOM9%2BSevNe6eKfC95rlwdC8J29%2FJ4JhnGoeJNeg%2FwBE%2FwCEkvMu%0AP%2BR0Of7Uz%2F1BOm4cHGSsJi6%2BNru7tZpySsla82mtG%2B1r63bW%2FNJ%2FlPG%2BFw%2BT4%2FMMlayL%2B0MraS%2Fs%0ADIFf7aja92r6q2y0u76ny14h13wjqNybK38E%2BDIrqb%2FSPI0L4bfD60u7rDPnT9O00aPjSsAf8xv%2F%0AAIqHryTw3hXi3xzb6VA9xL8KfCWlQ2UF3bwf8JJo%2FwAPrTV7nJb%2FAJhul6N%2FxKuen9tc5yema%2Bmv%0AipNHZwXlt4W0Lw54T0vTYLu2mv8AQ7fT9I%2Ftwgt%2FxL%2F7R1PnvgenPXJr8nfiD4ssbK8uLexvZb%2FU%0AzOLa4sdKtzdY%2FwBaPsGnaaTk7iPXjjOc8%2BphKVetWf1fH6%2FJ6Xlpo3y31tZP7N00pJfnWJeH%2BrNY%0AnA%2BknzXXxe9be%2Bmnvb2W6mdPr%2Fx8stLDW8Xw50G2upp18ieFvB4%2F0zLc%2FwBnapo%2FPTn0%2BU5OTnjR%0A%2B0VYXaR2MGlxQ3U045uPBfg7%2ByLk5Y86jpmjnrx06ZAyQGJ8ybwr4i1q4vdQurfS9GmEAFvYW9v9%0Ar1e5vdx%2Fs7UD%2Fag9F%2FHJ6ncKzI%2Fh5qekyTvLc2FrHLi4uJ9c1wf6SDuP%2FEu03TM9doPX05ymD79C%0AkrSckrXXR3es11b093prdrX3bv5yFWu%2Bb5aat9r6xdl6fO71PdbH4qXNzfNcRyWEd1b7beeD%2FhGv%0ABt3ac7%2F%2BJfqX%2FFH56fXqAck17L8OvjbYeFPEs0PjHw14c8SeHtSnsrgC%2FwDAng66%2BzWWSf8AiW%2F8%0ASgDGM9eec5JNfEH2W3vGjMXi%2BLUL6HHkWMF%2F%2FZOr23zNjjJ%2FtXODj06Yxnd1Muq3RSxlu9QtJRb6%0AVZecL64F3q9xkuP%2BQkfXBznocYzlicqmEtZ0NH35nqve1vfd722%2BLVs68JjvYV5Yla35XeNt05q%2B%0ArSs1ZtddNdj9b31zwJ4lso7rw54X8ETWgxmeDwb8PvsmMnP%2FADB%2BOffJ475qCG30eZLf%2FimvBH2o%0Az2Qz%2FwAIZ4O%2F0ognqP7HP%2BHJ98%2Fmh4Y1%2BTS7iLUNF8S6zoMsv%2BkTwZ%2B1aRc%2FMx%2F4mXzZP69BjOCa%0A%2BlvDfx2trC8tZ%2FEEmlpFZTmfz%2FINnaXOC3%2BnkZ%2F4lfH5ZI5PJ8aOFr4dO3o4tPXWWusrLSzWlnqr%0AtpSP0%2FL%2BMcqrYeUcwyLIla12uH93ea1u002knJN2ta11y830%2FD4b0%2BYXrnQvCUYxeeQZ%2FBfg0f8A%0AMRJH%2FMG5HH1HzZGSSaN5pVlbTELoXhcRz4%2F5kzwefs4yw76Ngd88%2B2Seay9E%2BMPh7VLWbVjNFaWu%0Asar%2FAK%2FA%2FwCPL7Bq2o6j%2FZvPrqPQe4znmuQ034q%2BGtXuptJtrqK0u54B5ME4z%2FyDS23vj34z2BOc%0AGuWp9fvK1rWVuWze8ttN%2FwALct22fT5vjgkZ55%2FPpnnIANP2rtaz5fVd%2B%2FL%2FXc%2BO5%2F9%0Ao%2Bq63va%2Bn82%2B17db28ttSqLlYHKDkc%2FLwO5xz19%2Bnc84znB8VXUNtpceozmOOX7QP3XPPJxwD9Mf%0AnwSTXEeNfFtr4SGdSOdUmg4spxgabgvngHH9qY29e3qSGDda%2BHfxU8ZT6PoEelXWgS3mh6J4gsWn%0A%2FwCJr9p0XUSw%2FtDTRpn%2FACFcj8ACTkk152JxPLeT%2BS%2F7elvrdyd7tu7S1d0tftslyX2CeJznolZ2%0AVtHO1pX0Wurve1lJJs%2BhPgV4dl8TXXiHxdKn2Xw7pFiNPsL77P8A6Xqes3%2Bnv%2FxL9NP4Lx1%2B6CeO%0AXWFvq1xe%2FwBq2ttLL50%2F2e%2FgyP8AiW3mW1Id%2FfI%2FHnk19H%2BCPhTqfgr9kPw14cEstprMHxN%2Ftie%2B%0AgH2W7ubJtPb2%2Bp78EDNbEEHhLxJpXnxPYeF%2FEU0H%2FE9sL7UP9E1O9%2FtB9NGv6aT0xuJOT3xnjJ%2BO%0AxFT2tf6smtNderu1fS76tLTd2uews0x1swzHC65ek%2Bi5XZz89UuaLV%2BZ3umlJ6%2BQp8RJfA0OuC35%0Ak06x%2FwBd9nF19pwW%2Fs3k9MYJ9DwO2T6z4Q8T3Hgb4VanqWr3P2vxb4k%2BxahmcYu7az1DUiNO0%2FUg%0AeOmpah%2BYA7k%2BL%2BN%2FCkjX%2Fh%2FTnufNhs57PUJwLj7V9p%2Fs5m%2Fs0dD1%2FPOc5A46fUn8Q6rL8PLC8tLr%0AS11%2FXLHUPtH2fN5c2QZs6h1J%2FwCJ2dvb%2FmH6KOQprTB0qLUnZPVWutbXqJ6X3trbr1bWp%2BQcRYrE%0AYyvmGIrvTTWN7XvNK92%2BujX8rXds8z%2BKHw1n8QfBb4d%2FCi1vvJj8R6r4z%2BKPjq%2BggJGm%2BGv7Rfw3%0A4c%2FtLk%2F8TTWx9uPhzRhn%2FkIsCSc15v4j8SeBvgjp%2BgaF%2FZdrcXWgQf8AFKfD7GnXf9h2WXGneIPG%0A2pZH%2FFUf2oATow%2BmeGNfQH7UPxE0f4VeHZoNFlFzfWuk6LbG4nxd3eo%2BJRp7%2FwBm6ByR%2FwAgTA1n%0Ap%2FyMTHgA1%2BY3w10fTNfvtS%2BJXxS8TRWtpN9s1g%2F2rPqI%2Fty805j%2FAMxLJ1b%2By%2Bn%2FABOe2W5OTX6d%0Agv8Ado9d%2Fl73676%2FfY%2FHcTSoqvOy67eSvayvro7%2BXNaySTf6x%2FsseMrm8tPE3xM%2BMms6X4X0aaC8%0AHhPw1fat9qu7m81BiDr%2BRrPfBPhzwZjsOeWruIvCfhr4%2FwDivUfC3w%2BSXXosi4nt9V1bUNK0i5%2BZ%0A%2FwDkJHUzoZ1TOc98YPXmvhD9mPxB8Fvi78W%2FDnhn4gN8UNQ1TWIBb6FfaHp%2FiDw98OtEsssNN%2Fs3%0Aw54aJ1XS9KwOut88rySM17h8VfAeq%2FCjxXeaz8KdZuvCcdjqo0%2Fw34k8Of2jdXl1eEtmw1L%2B0tZ1%0AsappeB%2FzGz0xySGB6sThfaprELs7u6e8kraPT4k1ro9btRYsJinSbtu7XUt5L39Uk9U%2Buul46NxT%0AfoHxH%2FZg8WaPbzaX4v8AiX4D%2BHttZ8f2JpVv4gu7S2%2B8NN%2F4lul6Pof0%2FwCJ3rfpnJIx%2Bd%2FxL%2BFf%0AgnRZWs5Pjho2v3MAH%2BgwX2n%2FAGPq%2FwD8T%2BZHPy8xfGX9rX40XRNlqHiq%2FivYIPs09xoerHxXaXPz%0AP%2FzDfEza7q2l9%2F8AhIv7E1zOP%2BRWOa%2BF%2FFvxS1XxAkcviaC1upTjyLixt%2F8AhH9Xu%2BW7Z%2BXHbPv6%0AmsqGVV4tvW6cbaJNu8tk5a31Vlr3bDE5zQoYd3bVmrXTWvNLztJa6KybaTs7TPT9Xs7ZmMdt4usL%0AqETjJsdW0%2B1%2Bz%2FeA40zWc9QM46cZyCc%2Bb6t%2FZRDRSXP28nFv%2B4vh83Lfltx68hupNeT3fi%2F7RHNb%0Axxy2tjnFvBPBYerDP6A4z7ZGGJwpdfc%2FxyTLk8wQ4%2FiYDjOeo%2FLb2JJ%2BgoYWth07ttNq%2BjS0c3or%0A6vXTr16pHzFTH0K8m046a2Tb0u%2Bm2tu133unf17Q47e4ujp%2F2eKOKaC8%2FwCfH%2FmHafqo%2Bh%2BnPXqS%0ABXn15MllJHGtxH5k%2FwDzwA7ZGefz%2FLjjFZOmnVLsW1ziWOPz7z%2FX6hqP%2FPg%2FbB46fmeCRzteHdGu%0AL0TSySeVYWUH%2FLD%2FAI%2B7n%2FiYnkDPHP8ATk8V2Uqb9672t8tX%2BP5JvV634HVrJO7bv0drbvXS3br3%0AWjabOv8ACkX2y5trP7P%2B6mns7eeCfOere59PzIycgV9IeCbi28W6nDqln%2B6uvPuriDz%2FAPsJN%2FoG%0AOvp19u26vnnS%2FwDiXA3EZ8qTUp%2F7O0nz%2FwDl2ssuf7Q1Ln%2FZyPZj2BJ9K%2BDmsR6X4sk%2B0Sy%2FZphp%0A9v8AaIIP%2BPbkjpn0HfnnJ5wTy1%2F4EvT%2FANuqG2G%2BGX%2Fbn%2Fpyoe0%2FEPwTH4d1%2BTxD4ct%2FKu5oLPWL%0Aixm%2F5etGBI1L6anog6%2Box1IzXt3ga5l1fwxpd55nE1iMHp03D1564PP0ORzyXxHvrjUfDt7IfKOv%0AeAvsP2nyODc6N4iZwM85%2FsvjPHIyBlg2Tv8AwYmjm8Kvbj%2FVWd9d2wHPYtqR6nv179TySOfksbpH%0A5S6b6TW976K79ervp%2B0cB1fZZq8O1bo99bylHvbdJ672W7jd7UtuZJCpl8oDPpwMkdQe5Az9R1K0%0AV1v2HzWmk8vB49eOWzxnoSenUZ64orz4UYyi3Ju6fS1uvdNvp6aqz3P3J4pvVW268z%2B0%2Bul9X11v%0Are7bPgr43fES6s%2FjV8ZbbPl%2BV8VPiXg4HB%2F4TLxUAcE87sDjOQc85Bz1%2FwAPfG99f6cV87zgCO3I%0AGTjHPfr174OSAa%2Bc%2FwBo7ULf%2Fhfvxpjt%2FKOfi38S%2Bv8A2ULxYOBn0x64%2BXJJ2mp%2FB%2Fi220iwMQPk%0Ay8dvUvjgjHIX1A%2BYc5GR7Ecsw9FfWV3s7tO9nN3eibta%2Fpy7tNv4jHeIOPxallzx3q2mtG6iTu21%0AfRO%2BstWru02fV1h4ica8fKly3GOvI3NyecdO3uBjIBPts%2Btywad9rjMUkpsb3Fvtz%2FpgLd88Z6%2Bv%0ABGSVyfivwzrFxeXR1eObyjD1g2%2Fe%2B9jkE4GCO%2BeuQSSa%2B%2BvgB4D%2FAOFrXlvFPc%2FZbGDVbHWL7z7f%0A%2Fj2stPY6aOpx%2FZfXr%2Fs5Jzx85meI%2BpXUvl2WstbK61fLZXstVe6kfUcGYDDrL5Z1mPxN907Lmk07%0ApJdE%2Br10abPPfAHwW8V%2FGzVEu5PtQkH2K3%2B0CDP2qy%2F4lvbGRyfr7nHP7xfszfALRvht4T8zXtOl%0AvptN0rFhB5H%2Bl8Fs2GmnGO3c%2FwB3GASDh%2FCrSvhT8M4Laym1TS7qWD7FbwMLgY%2BxZb%2BzuOOy455%2B%0AZsEkNn6fTxNpF6k1zZXthOf%2BeEE%2BOMkdc47A%2BuT1J3Z%2BSqY91E7J3d9dGt5fJbLo%2FhUbu3MPN8%2B%2B%0Aucyw6a7dL%2FGluvlrr7yb2u%2FIfiZbaX488BR698NSZoWg4J9uOvIPtk8V7l%2Bz7p%0AWg6NZ%2BLdSs7q%2FwBQur3VVt%2Ft99ffas2QLdB%2BX%2Fj3q2eu8atFp2mzSah4a0HWI4cbf%2BXW7GC2T1Ix%0AjPX%2BfFcX8H9Qs7nwwZLPw9f%2BF7G6vr3UIrG%2Bx9sucn5dQwD3AHTPqSSOfnM4rOlh9O6d7XtrNa6b%0Aaa2d9t3qfTZdSxHt3Z63itdW3errq21ZU153b0bXK%2Fo2G53zMBzGMYHrksSPToTnJ9gCRmp7y3S9%0AiMU0QOeozjoxxx7j%2BnOc1mW8Nu8HmR3MR6dvdh0ySeB%2F%2BsjLW8%2FJOHlz0zwBjljkZPOevXjjrkEf%0ADYnC4esn7ddru%2FZ6a6rX7%2Bl7noUaio3%2BryS1W12lZz3cpNK72v3kr2evCat8NdGvQ9xFEPMOzafU%0AAyDvz2PXoM%2BmaK2j4z8N2DzW9zq9r5vY%2BcBkZcHgsP7o79z9aK%2BUxPDHDarTScLaWut9Xt97utdX%0Auess%2FwA3V7Yv%2FwBK80uj6Wv530e59TaNL%2FxL7GPr%2FoNl%2FwCkD%2B%2Frn9evFaY0u4uAX%2FdWsQx%2Fr%2Be7%0A%2FwCHJ9cdcYNfwcB%2FZ1s%2F8f8AZVl83f72lj1x%2FwDrPOck2%2FPmlu8SSM%2F%2B9jsZcdv85PXnP76tb%2BVl%0A%2FWv9eZ8Kcxrem6dFFPJLFdajKCuPIOMcy5zgHj69mHPXPzd8SdB8N%2BJdA1zw7rvhGw1bRtSgW31b%0ASb641Bf7TsgXHHX8fYjrnNfZV7bQLbyYiTp6fX1J%2FLp054r5g8UnEmsY9R%2F6E%2F8A8SP85z7OVVGn%0AKOj5ZRSvqldytbqrcu3n3R8%2FxDgKGOy6pRrK6XK769faLTW6b3bX3Nn57fsrfGnQrP4i%2FED4cWVt%0AFpek6P4y1nw%2FYWM9x%2FyDf7OLf2bYevUHr%2Fe68cfpRcahHpa3l67eVBDALjqecMwGeQRg4z7Fs5HX%0A%2Be%2BGaXQ%2F%2BCkHxl0zSHNhYS6noepSWlvhYWv7rw%2FJ9ouipB%2FeS4%2BYjgc7QCST%2B7WpyyTeGJxK5cCw%0AGM%2FWT0Oe3r688nP6LmWFVJYSu7O9%2Fd17Tez01Ss%2F%2B3d7Nv8AjDhbM68aueUNP%2BE7PlyNNpSs2trv%0AXW9311ad2jJg%2BMck07GIS4JGR34JBIySfQ%2BuCMngZ5fWfF2oa1eNcb4h5OOYM9i%2BO%2FfkfiM5215b%0ApaL5kYwP9Reevv8A4nPrnnNdhp9vB9lm%2Fdr%2FAK8ev97Hr%2Fn1PWvMWGpX0jut3u0nJa7vo%2Br6btHv%0A0cwr4xyjPok3ro3ed9ElZe6na71te9kzYGs3CJGZm8qWHHbr80memfQZ6ZGO4wc7Vta1O5iml%2Fcm%0ALj1APzOM9e%2BPp0%2BbkmqMwG%2FHbdj8N2PX0%2F8A155rD1aeXyD856nsOzHH8z%2BfU1BlUrVFezS1jt%2F3%0AE73vfd9nbfUq3F9BcefJJKLWQQAdB2LY7Z57j02%2BhrPuFaMG5%2B0%2BbHnrjjhnwe%2FX%2FHkkGpGgh8mc%0A%2BWmfI9PQye%2F%2Be5NeRa5eXUN6UjnkReOA3H3iPr%2FkdcZoK515%2Fcv%2FAJI7i6svtEDySeV5uFB6nu3%2B%0AR7sewArldFuI9O1FPMklzDOPs%2FXHGR7%2B3fOSOpK11NlLILJfnPG3H%2FfUg759B%2Bnpk8lexRvqS7kU%0A46cemz39z%2BZ696fxSNqe8vT%2FANuOu8TXttcPFcXFzLFEP9I%2F9C7%2FAPfP07k8189eIdl3c3slnzD5%0A646D7VzID0z%2FAHcknPG3nIwfRvFs0vkTHe2fXP8An%2FPevPIFAFuB057n1k75z2%2FnycnOM%2Bnr%2BTl5%0A%2Bf4u99D18upqrWne3RLToudvrfVRWl9%2Btr35u0iFgZ7jJmmn%2Bw28EOMfaLwFz0zg7hn6e%2Bcj1bwv%0A8OIpZrW7%2BzxTe%2FQfeJGQR7%2FUdc5JNeDC6uT%2B0Z8CNEMznSr7VPEU95YZ%2FwBHnmSw0sLI6f3gOmCB%0A6gnmv0l8M2Nn9sQfZ48ccbff614OZ1HRcnu0o9dLylPbttva%2B1037x%2BycBZdQ%2Bov0u9LN2lZ6p6N%0Aqd9NG90zp%2Fhr8PpNkckkcsUXFvn8XHpznbn8uDgk%2ByajbW2h2U58uLyuPUdC3v34zzkDAz1x2vhq%0A3hh0mZIo1RfIPC5A4bHrn9fzPNeSfEG4m%2Fsi8%2FeN%2Bn96Qenp%2FwDrJ5r5k%2FUj5I%2BJep3Gu%2BIbLw9p%0A00o%2FtfVbC2zAM5ssuNROCc9CMfU9ly31fDoWh29vbWVvF5VrawWVtb9MEjdnnB6YBx068nIz8eeG%0AZpZfiXfNI5drWA%2FZycZiwxxs9Op6569TX19ojtLZ25kbf0PzY67mH9T%2BZ%2Bp%2FPs5zTEVc0%2Bpya5bL%0AXV6c8lte7197V9Ur%2B6m%2Fbpf7DQlXw91Ky3bV02l3b7uzbt3bd0XWjRRPm1n8s87cZ%2BbqOhJxjaTk%0A%2FUEnr5d4z1HWNK068gDZjlxbmeAkYyWwTkc5xkEe4Iyua9buDgM3c7cn6NIP5f5J5rn%2FABJDFLpc%0A%2FmIHxjGc%2FwB5ff8A2j%2BfU4rzM6y7E4bB5hXpYySa0SadtXUja9tlbTrZvRtHsZbmuHwtaX9qYKOY%0A7R1aS62snayfXdrpJu1vzP8AEXgvWbzVb29t%2FEF%2FFLcY22%2F2nrtY55PPU59jnnJor1bxnFHFrFwI%0A1CfKOn1PqT%2FnHpRX8m5rLDyzHFtZhnTXtOtenF%2FaSWk3fdat30V77n7M8noXevRd%2FwDP8z%2F%2F2Q%3D%3D%0A&seqNumber=1
```

it is very large string i just post first and last line

code for call

```
 RestAdapter restadapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                    .setEndpoint(API).build();
            final StoreImages storeImage = restadapter.create(StoreImages.class);
            storeImage.storeProfileImages(imgParams, new Callback<CreateUpdateResp>() {
                @Override
                public void success(CreateUpdateResp resp, Response response) {

                }
                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                }
            });
```

and it give me below response

```
 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 Connection: close
 Date: Fri, 14 Aug 2015 11:57:26 GMT
 Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 X-Android-Received-Millis: 1439553509055
 X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1439553508605
 <--- END HTTP (0-byte body)
```

Please help me to sore this out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo code that I use in my app to upload an image via Retrofit to an api.

```
  @Multipart
  @POST(APIEndPoint.CLIENTS + "/{clientId}/images")
  public void uploadClientImage(@Path("clientId") int clientId,
                                  @Part("file") TypedFile file,
                                  Callback<Response> responseCallback);
```

- Make sure @Multipart is added to the method
- Use TypedFile to send your Base64 Encoded stuff

Comment: Hi Ishan thansk for reply. I here i found Typefile is retrofit.mimetype and i have base64 as string how can i use it?Also can i send multiple parameters like sequenceNo, user name etc?