# how to send Image file with Retrofit(@Fields)

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipart

Here I m using `@Fields` data with `@FormUrlEncoded` But I have to use both in same API `@Part("user_image") RequestBody file` with `@Multipart`. How does it possible? Thanks in advance.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/datingapp/index.php/Webservice")
Call<Result> signupUser(@Field("user_name") String name,
                             @Field("age") String age,
                             @Field("work") String work,
                             @Field("home_town") String home_town,
                             @Field("gender") String gender,
                             @Field("interest") String interest,
                             @Field("study") String study,
                             @Field("email") String email,
                             @Field("password") String password,
                             @Field("device_id") String device_id,
                             @Field("device_type") String device_type,
                             @Part("user_image") RequestBody file,
                             @Field("signup") String signup);
```

Comment: You can send an image in the form of Base64 string. I never used Retrofit although have a look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787585/android-retrofit-base64-body) and [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009612/retrofit-send-base64-encoded-string-in-parameters)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Http protocol not allow 2 Content-Type in the same request. So you have to choose :

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data

You use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by using annotation `@FormUrlEncoded` in order to send image you have to transform the whole file into text (e.g. base64).

A better approach would be use `multipart/form-data` by describing your request like that :

```
@Multipart
@POST("/datingapp/index.php/Webservice")
Call<Result> signupUser(@Part("user_name") String name,
                         @Part("age") String age,
                         @Part("work") String work,
                         @Part("home_town") String home_town,
                         @Part("gender") String gender,
                         @Part("interest") String interest,
                         @Part("study") String study,
                         @Part("email") String email,
                         @Part("password") String password,
                         @Part("device_id") String device_id,
                         @Part("device_type") String device_type,
                         @Part("user_image") RequestBody file,
                         @Part("signup") String signup);
```

Comment: @KoVartthan The behavior is the same as POST so technically yes

Comment: if i send as a Mutlipart data , i cant send form-data in the put method .......i want to send both mutlipart and form data in the same request @Lionel Briand

Comment: As said in the answer the protocol itself doesn't allow that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5809704/4681367

Answer (score 0):

```
@Multipart
@POST("/datingapp/index.php/Webservice")
Call<Result> signupUser(@PartMap Map<String,String> queryMap,
                             @Part("user_image") RequestBody file);
```

Here the `@PartMap` contains the required other parameters which is nothing but a `HashMap` containing key and values e.g,

```
LinkedHashMap<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
map.put("user_name",username);
```

like above and so on.

Answer (score -3):

Make api call like this  :

```
@POST("/datingapp/index.php/Webservice")
@FormUrlEncoded
@Multipart
Call<Result> signupUser(@FieldMap LinkedHashMap<String, String> data,@Part RequestBody file);
```

and pass your data is the form of key and value in `LinkedHashMap` like this

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
data.put("user_name", user_name);
data.put("age", age);
data.put("work", work);
data.put("work", work);
data.put("gender", gender); and so on ....
```

for getting image in `Multiparts` :

```
RequestBody file= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file);
```

final call to hit the api :

```
Call<Result> call = apiService.signupUser(data ,file);
```

Hope this works :)

Comment: `@Multipart` annotation can not use with `@FormUrlEncoded`, and `@FieldMap` shoule be `@PartMap`